# Overextending object design by adding many trivial fields?

Tags: oop

I have to add a bunch of trivial or seldom used attributes to an object in my business model.

So, imagine class Foo which has a bunch of standard information such as Price, Color, Weight, Length. Now, I need to add a bunch of attributes to Foo that are rarely deviating from the norm and rarely used (in the scope of the entire domain). So, Foo.DisplayWhenConditionIsX is true for 95% of instances; likewise, Foo.ShowPriceWhenConditionIsY is almost always true, and Foo.PriceWhenViewedByZ has the same value as Foo.Price most of the time.

It just smells wrong to me to add a dozen fields like this to both my class and database table. However, I don't know that wrapping these new fields into their own FooDisplayAttributes class makes sense. That feels like adding complexity to my DAL and BLL for little gain other than a smaller object. Any recommendations?

Comment: If the implemented language supports it, you can at least use partial classes that at least logically break off the lesser used attributes for maintainablity.  Less visual interference with popping open the hood of your class.

Comment: @hydroparadise, this still leaves me with the problem in my DB, and I haven't investigated using partial classes with my ORM (PetaPoco), but I'm writing in c# and using partial classes is a great idea, thanks!

Comment: On the DB side, dont forget One to One relationships.  Get the drift?

Comment: That was one of my concerns: Does the performance hit of a join to another table of otherwise useless data outweigh significantly expanding the Foo table, in your opinion?

Comment: As with any other answer, it depends.  How big is the current table?  Will the joining attributes be indexed?  One way or another, a join will put a hit on performance. But the point of splitting would be able to give the option, in code, as to pull from second table or not.  Otherwise a simple join is not that expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up a separate storage class/struct for the rarely used fields and hold it as a single field, say "rarelyUsedFields" (for example, it will be a pointer in C++ and a reference in Java - you don't mention your language.)

Have setters/getters for these fields on your class. Setters will check if the value is not the same as default and lazily initialize `rarelyUsedFields`, then set the respective field value (say, `rarelyUsedFields.DisplayWhenConditionIsX = false`). Getters they will read the `rarelyUsedFields` value and return default values (true for `DisplayWhenConditionIsX` and so on) if it is `NULL`, otherwise return `rarelyUsedFields.DisplayWhenConditionIsX`.

This approach is used quite often, see WebKit's [Node.h](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/Node.h) as an example (and its `focused()` method.)

Comment: I'm writing in C#. I had thought of using a component object, how would you suggest I store the data in my schema relative to the original Foo object?

Comment: Are you talking about a scope issue between properties?  Otherwise just pass from Foo to the subcomponent the connection/location information to the child component for schema access.

Comment: Apologies, not familiar with C#, but it certainly should have a means to delegate the property getting/setting.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, I was more referring to the actual database storage, but I think I've worked out a design now.

Comment: Sorry I did not get this from your original question. It was marked with the "oop" tag rather that something database-related, that's why I stuck to the programming-related design.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction makes your question a bit hard to understand, but I would suggest using custom getters such as `Foo.getPrice()` and `Foo.getSpecialPrice()`.

The first one would simply return the attribute, while the second would perform operations on it first.

This is only possible if there is a way to calculate the "seldom used version" from the original attribute value, but in most common cases this would be possible, providing you can access data from another object storing parameters, such as `FooShop.getCurrentDiscount()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the possible new values can be calculated using the preexisting data in the object. My main concern is best practices to avoid cluttering my code and schema and the custom getters would add just as much, if not more, pollution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is more about the Foo object having side effects. 
In your example, I see two features : display and price.

I would build one or many Displayer (who knows how to display) and make the price a component object, with a list of internal price modificators.

Note all this is relevant only if your Foo objects are called by numerous clients.